# Embedding Ruby into a nanoc site doesn't work

Tags: html, ruby, erb, nanoc

When I attempt to loop through `sorted_articles()` in Ruby, the embedded code just stays the same and doesn't get compiled in the output when I run `nanoc compile`. Why is this? Am I embedding it wrong? I've tried all the variations below:

```
<%= for item in sorted_articles()
<p>item[:title]</p>
 end %>
```

also

```
<% for item in sorted_articles() %>
<p>item[:title]</p>
<% end %>
```

and

```
<% sorted_articles().each do |item| %>
<p>item[:title]</p>
<% end %>
```

and finally

```
<%= sorted_articles().each do |item|
<p>item[:title]</p>
end %>
```

I also followed a tutorial [here](http://clarkdave.net/2012/02/building-a-static-blog-with-nanoc/) pretty much exactly as I found it, but still no luck! The routing is working, so are the rules, and everything else. Just this damn loop!

Thanks. The source can be found on [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/roconnor/roconnor.gitlab.io/blob/master/content/index.html#L19) and the live site can be found [here](http://roconnor.gitlab.io)

Comment: It seems that you have working version in your repo. (`<%= item[:name] %>`)

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev, just running CI now. Please post as answer

Comment: Nah, you answered it, not me :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev the `<%= item[:name] %>` isn't working. Just tried it.

Comment: Hm, it should work, as far as I can see.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Well it's not. It must be an issue with my `sorted_articles()` imported from `Nanoc::Blogging`, but I don't know why that's not working...

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "the embedded code just stays the same and doesn't get compiled"?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev if you go to [my site](http://roconnor.gitlab.io), you'll see. The code isn't even compiled, it just gets passed through

Comment: Ah, I see. In this case, it has nothing to do with `sorted_articles`. It's like ruby processing is not active on that file.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev that's an interesting thought. I've just noticed that I'm not mentioning `erb` in the rule. How would I do that? IS it a filter? I was just about to test the theory but gitlab is down -.-

Comment: I have no idea about nanoc, but yes, adding ERB in the pipeline (or however it is done there) should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compile rule for all `.html` files wasn't being passed through the `erb` filter, and as Sergio mentioned in the comments, the code was being ignored. Adding the `filter :erb` fixed the issue